# Glassfish Amazon AWS EC2 instances and ELB caching issue

Tags: glassfish, amazon-ec2, ejb, load-balancing

I have 2 EC2 instances running Glassfish app server (running the exact same deployed application) and these run under an Elastic Load Balancer. This is working great but I am worried about caching inconsistencies with the EJBs.

Situation:
Client sends request to ELB which forwards to EC2 instance 1. Some EJB object, let's call it EJB1, gets cached.
Client --> ELB --> EC2-1 (EJB1 cached)

A short time later Client sends another request but this gets forwarded now to EC2 instance 2. EJB1 now is cached on that instance.
Client --> ELB --> EC2-2 (EJB1 cached)

A short time later Client sends another request and is forwarded to EC2 instance 1. EJB1 is still in cache but is not up to date, thus causing a cache inconsistency.
Client --> ELB --> EC2-1 (EJB1 cached)

Unfortunately I haven't been able to actually see this issue yet but I feel that it's a possibility. Other than turning caching of EJBs off, what is the proper way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon provides "[session stickiness](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/04/08/support-for-session-stickiness-in-elastic-load-balancing/)" support at the load balancer. This means, assuming the user has cookies enabled, they are sent to the same EC2 instance for the lifetime of their session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would certainly work I would think, however it would require modification of our application (this is for an iOS native application). It is something we will look into.

Answer (score 1):

Until you implement a level 2 cache your instances are not going to share the cache.

Here are a couple of links for level 2 caching solutions. 
(open source) http://www.terracotta.org/ehcache/
(lots of cash) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer - it's something we have to look into as we scale up. For now we have disabled caching on the application servers.